# multi path Array of objects mutation

Tags: polymer-1.0

Wanna mutate a path of array of Obj.

The object should change on-click and it looks like this:

```
<iron-icon id="id" icon="icons:arrow-downward" on-click="_sortTags"
class$="arrow [[sortData.id.icon]] [[sortData.id.state]]"></iron-icon>
```

Here i wanna mutate the sortData Obj, this function gets triggered on click on the above icon

```
_changeSortData(field,order,iconShape,status){ //there is a function calls this function but did not bring it here to make issue simple
        this.set('sortData[field].sort', order);
        this.set('sortData[field].icon', iconShape);
        this.set('sortData[field].state', status);

      }
```

The object below is the property:

```
sortData: {
          type: Object,
          value: function () {
            return {
              "id": {
                "icon": "downward",
                "sort": "default",
                "state": "inactive"
              },
              "date": {
                "icon": "downward",
                "sort": "default",
                "state": "inactive"
              }
            }
          },
        },
```

Now is it possible to escape single qoutes here in order to apply [field] as a pram

```
this.set('sortData[field].sort', order);
```

since there is tow fields in sortData Obj (id and data)

Comment: Why do you say it won't work? It seems to work in this [demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/Jvrwgq?editors=1010).

Comment: @tony19 could not relize that, gonna edit the qestion please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`this.set(path, value)`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.Element#method-set), `path` can be specified as a `string` **or an `Array`**. Since you have a dynamic path part, you would use an `Array` path like this:

```
this.set(['sortData', field, 'sort'], order); // `field` is dynamic
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/Jvrwgq?editors=1010)